# solving 3-d coordinates from x, y and z distance

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I working with WiFi positioning and i want to know the exact coordinate where I am.
    Here is the problem..[image: 3d Coordinate Problem]

Answer (score 2):

First, let's divide everything by 10, to make it easier.

Using the distance between D and AP1:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + (2-5)^2 = 3^2
$$
Using the distance between D and AP2:
$$
(x-5)^2 + y^2 + (2-5)^2 = 5^2
$$
The first equation gives
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 0
$$
which means that $x=0$ and $y=0$. But the second equation gives:
$$
x^2 + y^2 -10x + 9 = 0
$$
and this equation is not satisfied by $x=0$ and $y=0$.

So, your particular measurements describe an impossible situation.

In general, you write down two equations that express the distances, as I did above. Each equation will contain an $x^2 + y^2$ term, but you can get rid of these by subtracting. This gives you a single linear equation involving $x$ and $y$ that is easy to solve.

Comment: sorry. the information is not accurate but that is the scenario. Actually i am formulating an algorithm. by the way, is there any algorithm for that?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: thanks. I have to program it in c++ or JavaScript. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. But, if you want someone to write the code for you, it's probably better to ask on Stackoverflow. This site is for mathematics.

Comment: @bubba: SO is not for finding *someone else* for writing code for you - better look on rent-a-coder.com for that.

Comment: @Doc -- sure, that's not the intent, but it's often the result. Anyway, my main point was that this is not the right place, and I'm not going to write the code  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not an expert but if I am correct by forming system of equations :
$D= \sqrt{((x_{1}-x_{2})^2+(y_{1}-y_{2})^2+(z_{1}-z_{2})^2)}$
$D'=\sqrt{((x_{2}-x_{3})^2+(y_{2}-y_{3})^2+(z_{2}-z_{3})^2)}$
you would get your solution..
And .. Either I'm wrong or the solution to this doesn't exist in real plane..

Comment: hi. distance is already computed which is supplied in the diagram. I want to know the exact coordinates of point D where z is known.

Comment: I know distance is computed, this is merely a formula. Plugging in the values from the drawing,You would get the same result as in the bubba's answer I.e. such triangle cannot exist in real plane.